# If execute sql task is non executed move to next process

Tags: ssis

In My ssis package i am executing execute sql task , this contains store procedure execution if its not executed properly move to next process . i have attached the screen shot, thank you[image]

Comment: You can change the green connector's condition from Success to Completion. Perhaps, you should check a tutorial on SSIS before creating a package

Answer (score 0):

Use a error Output(Red Line) and continue your process

http://www.kingswaysoft.com/Frontend/Images/help-manual/ssis-integration-toolkit-sharepoint/SharePoint%20Error%20Output.png